# What is the difference between R hat and psrf?

Tags: bayesian, bugs, stan

In convergence diagnosis in WinBUGS/JAGS/Stan, there are different statistics reported for each variable. In WinBUGS/Stan, Rhat ($\hat{R}$) is reported. In JAGS with the `runjags` package, psrf (Potential Scale Reduction Factor) is reported (it is basically generated by `coda::gelman.diag()`). Values close to 1 (i.e. < 1.05) are considered to be "good" (i.e. the chains converged).

What is the difference between R hat and psrf?

Answer (score 8):

$\hat{R}$ and "potential scale reduction factor" refer to the same thing. See [Chapter 6](http://www.mcmchandbook.net/HandbookChapter6.pdf) of the [Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo](http://www.mcmchandbook.net/index.html), "Inference from Simulations and Monitoring Convergence" by Andrew Gelman and Kenneth Shirley.

In Stan, the number reported is actually split $\hat{R}$; the calculation of $\hat{R}$ is computed with each of the chains split in half.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! What is the point of splitting the chain in half in Stan? Why is it done in Stan and not in WinBUGS/JAGS?

Comment: I assume $\hat{R}$ is computed in half-chain, means excluding warm-up steps; that let you do, comparison not only within a Chain, but also across chains.

Comment: The point of splitting is to handle the cases where the individual chains cover the target distribution, but fail to converge to each other (simply: they wander independently on each othe over the parameter domain).

See: A. Gelman, et. al., Bayesian Data Analysis, Third Edition. In the footnote 2, pg. 285, they explicitly address this issue.